# Add /src/main/java folder to Arquillian for deployment

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I want to add all java packages (and classes) from src/main/java folder to the Arquillian deployment, as follow:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ArquillianDeployment {

@Deployment
public static Archive<?> deploy() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .// add here all java packages from src/main/java folder
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addPackages` instead.

```
ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
    .addPackages(true, "my.rootPackage");
```